# Jquery post getting empty response from a servlet data request

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

When I do a resquest from my angular application my servlet recibe correctly the request data, but when I try to response from my servlet to my angular, it doesn't recibe anything.

My request

```
     $.post({
    url:'/LegoRepository/CoreServlet',
      data:{
        angular:"a"
      },
      //type:'post',
      cache:false,
      success:function(responseText){
        console.log("Credentials" + responseText);

      },
      error:function(){
        console.log('Ajax Error');
        }
  });
```

My servlet

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8");  
System.out.println(request.getParameter("name"));
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
        json.put("Name", "ManojSarnaik");
         out.print(json.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
out.close();
```

Comment: Apart from that your question does not relate to angular4 since your are using jquery, you need to flush your stream with out.flush().

Comment: You should isolate this type of things with curl. Use curl/postman/etc to make sure the server side works. Then if something is missing, it has to be the client side